# Breadth First Search of a graph HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> in a word ladder game implementation

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, breadth-first-search

I am making a game called Word Ladders, the game goes that you would change one character from a word each time to get to a new word and eventaully we want to hit the end word from a start word. All the words are contained in a dictionary which I used a HashSet for. Basically I am at the point where I have constructed my graph in a HashMap were the String key is the current word and the ArrayList contains all of the words that are 1 character off. What I am trying to do now is to construct a search of the word key against all of the words stored in the array list to and keep doing that over and over until I hit the target end word then record the path that was displayed maybe in a list or something.

So What I got so far is:

```
package ladder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Dolphin
 */
public class Ladder {

    public HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    public HashSet<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Queue<String> ladder = new LinkedList<>();
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> path1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    public Queue<String> myQ = new LinkedList<>();

    public String startingWord;
    public String endingWord;

    public void Ladder1(String filename, String start, String end)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        startingWord = start;
        endingWord = end;
        loadlist(filename, start.length());//we cut the list down
        for (String thewords : words) {
            graph.put(thewords, new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        makeGraph(words, graph);
        Bfs(startingWord, endingWord, graph, path);
        //GeneratePath(graph,path,end,path1);
        //System.out.print(path1);
        // makeLadder(startingWord, endingWord, words);
        //next we wana add each word to the array list, and make new array lists of words that are one character off
        //then you find the shortest path of the grap
    }

    //first thing we do is seperate the words from the list by length of the start word
    public void loadlist(String filename, Integer length)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
            String word = scan.nextLine();
            if (word.length() == length) {
                words.add(word);
            }
        }
    }

    public void makeGraph(HashSet<String> words, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph) {
        for (String x : graph.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> xterms = graph.get(x);
            for (String y : graph.keySet()) {
                ArrayList<String> yterms = graph.get(y);
                if (getDifference(x, y) == 1) {
                    if (!xterms.contains(y)) {
                        xterms.add(y);
                    }
                    if (!yterms.contains(x)) {
                        yterms.add(x);
                    }
                }
                graph.put(y, yterms);
            }
            graph.put(x, xterms);
        }
        //System.out.print(graph);
    }

    public void Bfs(String start, String end, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph, ArrayList<String> path) {
        ArrayList<String> newpath = path;
        ArrayList<String> stuff = graph.get(start);//we get the arraylist 
        for (int i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++) {
            myQ.add(stuff.get(i));
        }
        while (!myQ.isEmpty()) {
            String w = myQ.poll();
            newpath.add(w);
            if (!w.equals(end)) {
                newpath.clear();
                Bfs(w, end, graph, newpath);
            } else {
                newpath = path;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getDifference(String word1, String word2) {
        int difference = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < word1.length(); i++) {
            if (word1.charAt(i) != word2.charAt(i)) {
                difference++;
            }
        }
        return difference;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Ladder lad = new Ladder();
        lad.Ladder1("wordList.txt", "roil", "food");
    }
}
```

So pretty much my hashmap graph contains all the words in a file i pass through, I want to conduct a breadth first search on that graph where the graph is like the HashMap> i contain the graph in, I have a start word and a ending word that I want to search for and use. I also want to store the path that is used to get from the start word to the end word and eventually print it out. If someone could help implement the breadth first search or guide me on how to do that it would be really appreciated. Ive been stuck on this for a very long time.

So ive updated my Bfs to be like this from what was described below:

```
public void Bfs(String start, String end, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> graph, ArrayList<String> path) {
    ArrayList<String> newpath = path;
    ArrayList<String> stuff = graph.get(start);//we get the arraylist 
    for (int i = 0; i < stuff.size(); i++) {
        myQ.add(stuff.get(i));
    }
    while (!myQ.isEmpty()) {
        String w = myQ.poll();
        newpath.add(w);
        if (!w.equals(end)) {
            newpath.clear();
            Bfs(w, end, graph, newpath);
        } else {
            newpath = path;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know how to store the word path, and im getting a stack overflow error, if anyone knows how to fix this, it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: `I want to conduct a breadth first search on that graph` Use a `Queue`: once you have a start word, add all List items in the Map valued to this word to the `Queue`. Then for each word **W** in the Queue, pop it off, if it does not equal the end word add all words valued to **W** in the Map to the Queue. The path to the end word can be stored in a List

Comment: Hey I think I got what you where saying, I think its being implemented correctly, how exactly would i store the path for the word when i do reach the end word? What your describing I think I implemented it correctly, could you let me know if its done wrong? I posted it updated above in the question, Im not sure, I think its correct from how you were describing, but what I really dont understand is how to store the path exactly.

Comment: Doesn't look like a breadth-first-search, but a depth-first-search. You may think about moving the Queue so it's scope isn't specific to each method call during the recursion phase.

Comment: `but what I really dont understand is how to store the path exactly` You can pass a List to the 'Bfs' which contains the current Path (if you do so, be sure about creating new Lists for each call so their 'lines don't get crossed'). Then return this List from `Bfs` when the termination criteria is met (or store it elsewhere)

Comment: So im getting a stack overflow error at the line with the recursive call. Ive updated it to take a global array list called path to store the list path, although im clearing it everytime we dont hit the end word so that should be be okay until the path hits the end word, i think, ive updated it accordingly above, would you know how to fix the stack overflow error? is it because the queue is now global and getting too much data? im not sure

Comment: Implementing such a function recursively will almost certainly produce stackoverflow errors. Try to implement it iteratively instead to be more efficient with your resources.